# childNodes for documentElement returns one null

Tags: javascript

I am performing some simple JS test for traversing and i was wondering why my documentElement consist of one null object?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Some header</h1>
        <p id="pID">Some paragraph</p>
        <p name="pNAME">Another paragraph/p>
    </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var rootElement = document.documentElement;
    var childNodes = rootElement.childNodes;

    for (var i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
      document.write(childNodes[i].localName);
      document.write("<br>");
    }
</script>
```

It returns `head, null, body`. But why is there 3 `childNodes` in the `rootElement`?

Comment: `document.write` rewrites DOM, so I wouldn't expect anything meaningful with your code.

Comment: There are some white space characters between `</head>` and `<body>` and text nodes probably don't have a local name. Try `childNodes[i].nodeName` instead.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `.children()` instead which returns the elements rather than all nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you list only the objects instead of their `localName` you will see:

```
[object HTMLHeadElement]
[object Text]
[object HTMLBodyElement]
```

So you receive `null` for the `localName` of the text node. To fix this you need `children` instead of `childNodes`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var rootElement = document.documentElement;
    var childNodes = rootElement.children;

    for (var i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
      document.write(childNodes[i]);
      document.write("<br>");
    }
</script>
```

Here is demo in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgechev/aCBSE/).

Answer (score 1):

The new line between `</head>` and `<body>` is considered as text (`[object Text]`), so it's `.localName` attribute is `null`.

If you try this it should output only 2 elements

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>My document</title>
    </head><body>
        <h1>Some header</h1>
        <p id="pID">Some paragraph</p>
        <p name="pNAME">Another paragraph</p>
    </body>
</html>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var rootElement = document.documentElement;
        var childNodes = rootElement.childNodes;

        for (var i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
          document.write(childNodes[i].localName);
          document.write("<br>");
        }
    </script>
```